# Forgotten VBA keyboard shortcut

Tags: excel, keyboard-shortcuts, vba

I assigned my macro to a keyboard shortcut in Excel-VBA. It was a long time ago and I forgot to which key. How can I see it?

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862306/excel-vba-to-list-key-bindings-onkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{F12}", "MyMacro"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Bring up the Macro dialog box (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> or Macros on the View ribbon).

[image]

Select your macro.

Click the **Options** button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was the first place I looked at. It's empty but I'm sure that I could launch it from the keyboard.